# SSRS Highlight Cells on Click

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

Is there a way in SSRS Report Builder to create an OnClick event to highlight cells (change their background color) when a user clicks on a cell?  For example, I have a report with a lot of numbers on it spanning several years. I'd like to create functionality so when the user clicks on a cell (say, revenue for 2015), the revenue cells for all the other years highlight as well, to make comparing these values quick and easy.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/33RYe.png

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Actions within SSRS.

If you look at this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/05/20/multi-player-gaming-in-rs-aka-bi-power-hour-2008.aspx), and the attached project, you will see that clicking on cell causes it to change.

I imagine you can adapt the ideas here to suit your own purposes.

Good luck and if you want further help please let me know.

Ash

Comment: BAH. I don't have the permissions to restore a database here at the office. I guess I'll have to play around with this at home.